# Renaming file on zend framework throws 404 page not found error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an issue with my zend framework application. I have renamed a file in a folder from add.phtml to ad.phtml and changed the information from where it is referenced like below :

```
<div class="bottom-margin-less">
     <a href="<?php echo $this->url('customers/default', array('action' => 'ad'), array('force_canonical' => true)); ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-iconed btn-success">
     <i class="icon-plus"></i> 
     <?php echo $this->translate('label_21', null, $this->layout()->lang); ?></a>
</div>
```

Notice the 'action' => 'ad' it used to be 'action' => 'add'. This throws a 404 error when i rename the file to ad.phtml. Is there anywhere else i have to rename before it works or does zend framework have a different way of renaming files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure you have updated your action name to match the view. Make sure the addAction has been changed to adAction.

Comment: you are right it was supposed to be adAction instead of addAction

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your routing as well. I can not provide You with code snippet since You did not specify version of Zend Framework that you use.

Example: 
[Zend 2.1 documentation about routing.](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html)